# Is this approach secure enough to store OAuth tokens?

Tags: node.js, security, encryption, oauth-2.0

I'm building a Node app utilizing the Twitch OAuth API and I need to store the user's access and refresh tokens. I did some Google research and mostly followed [the Nest.js docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/encryption-and-hashing) (since I'm using Nest).

This is the code to encrypt the tokens. IV and salt are created beforehand (using `crypto.randomBytes(16)`) and passed as parameters.

```js
const key = (await promisify(scrypt)(process.env['CRYPT_PW'], salt, 32)) as Buffer,
    cipher = createCipheriv('aes-256-ctr', key, iv);

return Buffer.concat([
    cipher.update(token),
    cipher.final(),
]);
```

The `CRYPT_PW` is stored in an environment variable, IV and salt are stored alongside with the respective users keys in the DB. Is this secure enough to store OAuth tokens? If not, what do I need to change? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say in general yes, it's secure enough. I do it my self similar to this. However, I have a few remarks that are important to ensure and others might also find useful.

1. The `CRYPT_PW` should be at least 64 characters long to take maximum advantage of the full strength of AES 256-bit encryption.
2. `CRYPT_PW` should be stored in some kind of secure storage and fetched once during deployment. For example if you are using AWS you can use the Secrets Manager.
3. You don't necessarily need to generate a random salt because the IVs will produce different ciphers for the same keys anyway.